# conflict beetwen :after selector and overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi guys I've encountered a problem with css and html ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sg5Y/6/))

My problem is that, the `<div class="bcont"></div>` on the right of the `<div class="square></div>` has a script that make it scroll from right to left when the *mouse is over* the `square` `<div>`. So, to make it work I have to set

```
.square{
  font-family: 'Lobster Two';
  background-color: rgba(196, 196, 193, 0.3);
  /* color: rgba(196, 196, 193, 0.3); */
  color: #000;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 160px; 
  margin:30px; 
  border: solid 10px #000; 
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;  /* this! */
}
```

so the `bcont` `<div>` appears only when it move inside the `square` on `muoseover`. But, setting `overflow: hidden` on "square" div , the arrow (created by "square:after" rule) doesn't show up, and it is killing me. 
Sorry for my English.

Thank you all !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3sg5Y/7/

Comment: it doesnt solve my problem.. was I misunderstood?

Comment: man explain briefly what u want?

Comment: man, my problem is that the arrow should be visible and the "bcont" div should be visible only on mouseover, I think I wrote it young man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will not give overflow property on square box and instead of animating div from right to left you can animate on its width you can get effect you want.

```
$('#quotae').hover(function(){
  $(".bcont", this).stop().animate({width:'60px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
  }, function() {
  $(".bcont", this).stop().animate({width:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
});
```

I mean first keep width to 0 and than make it to 60 px; with that you also need to add overflow hidden on bcont div.

```
.bcont{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px; /* -60 */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

Check on http://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu414/3sg5Y/10/